# Is "sell" used intransitively to mean "achieve satisfactory sales" here?

Tags: meaning

**The passage**

> The program has little online presence. Searches for 911 call analysis
> in national court dockets come up virtually empty too. A public
> defender in Virginia said, “I have never heard of any of that claptrap
> in my jurisdiction.” Dozens of other defense attorneys had similar
> reactions. One thought the premise sounded as arbitrary as medieval
> trials by fire, when those suspected of crimes were judged by how well
> they could walk over burning coals or hold hot irons.
>
> Could it be true that Harpster, a man with no scientific background
> and next to no previous homicide investigation experience, had
> successfully **sold** the modern equivalent to law enforcement across the
> U.S. almost without notice?

*Source* - https://www.propublica.org/article/911-call-analysis-fbi-police-courts

---

**The question**

It's an unusual usage for me. Am I right in thinking the selling is intransitive?

The SOED lists a definition of sell (intrans) as:

> Make over or dispose of a thing to another; esp. dispose of
> merchandise, possessions, etc., to a buyer at a specified price.

And [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sell) has:

> to achieve a sale also : to achieve satisfactory sales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of sold in your sentence is in the transitive sense as described by [Merriam-Webster's definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sell) 5a and 5b under the transitive verb header:

> 5a: to develop a belief in the truth, value, or desirability of : gain acceptance for ("trying to *sell* a program to the Congress")

> 5b: to persuade or influence to a course of action or to the acceptance of something ("*sell* children on reading")

Rather than selling a good or service, Harpster persuaded or influenced law enforcement to accept what the author calls the "modern equivalent" of "medieval trials by fire."

Answer (score 3):

This is transitive. Harpster sells "the modern equivalent" to law enforcement.  (Or at least, it may have been sold.)

The M-W definition that best matches my reading is 5b: to persuade or influence to a course of action or to the acceptance of something

An intransitive usage would be "Sex sells."